# powershell, weird parameters parsing when ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true

Tags: powershell

say I define the following function

```
function test {
    Param ([parameter(mandatory=$false, position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][object[]]$args)

    $args
}
```

and that the function is mistakenly called with an ill-formed string
`test 'filter=(type:'foo')'`

I was expecting an error to be raised but instead I get the following output:

```
filter=(type:
foo)
```

did I miss something or is this a bug in PowerShell arguments parsing? or a *feature* due to `ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true`?

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.3031
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.3031
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: yeah, you can pass an indefinite amount of arguments when `ValueFromRemainingArguments` is enabled (or your function is non advanced). in this case `'filter=(type:'foo')'` is parsed as 2 separated arguments.

Comment: also this might help you see how it is being parsed: `{ test 'filter=(type:'foo')' }.Ast.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandElementAst] }, $false)`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon why is ```foo')'``` parsed as a single ```BareWord```? are ```'``` allowed inside a word? where can I find a definition of what PS _think_ is a word?

Comment: see argument mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4#argument-mode and StringConstantType enum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.stringconstanttype?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `'filter=(type:'foo')'`

indeed **becomes *two* arguments** in a command call ([argument-mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode) statement), as follows:

- Argument 1:

  - The value of `'filter=(type:'`, which turns into verbatim `filter=(type:`
  - **Unfortunately, PowerShell does *not* support Bash-style *compound string arguments*** (e.g., `echo 'foo'bar"baz"` turning into verbatim `foobarbaz` when executed in Bash) **if the compound argument *starts with a quoted string***: whatever follows is considered the start of the *next* argument.
- Argument 2:

  - `foo')'` is therefore considered a *separate* argument, but **here a compound string *is* supported, because the first part is an *unquoted* string (bareword)**; thus, it turns into verbatim `foo)`